# AJAX Database make high CPU process

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

My Code for requast number notification :

```
function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var Bil = xhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("MsgNoti").innerHTML = Bil;

            if ( Bil != ""){    
                if (ChkSession != "Mobile"){
                    window.open("Message/ViewMsgPopUp.asp", "", "width=900,height=600,top=25,left=100");
                }
            }
         }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "CheckMsg1.asp", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

This is code in CheckMsg1.asp

```
SQL ="select count(MsgID) over() as bil, MsgID from Msg where PopUpStatus = 'TRUE'"
set read = conn.execute(SQL)
if read.eof then
  Bil = "0"
else
  Bil1= read("bil")
end if

read.close()
Conn.Close()
response.write(Bil1)
```

Any problem with my code? Why this code make high CPU process in server when 25 - 30 user use. AJAX be run in 7 second use Javascript timer. Please help any suggestion for me? This code run in ASP Classic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you  try this

```
select count(MsgID)  from Msg where PopUpStatus = 'TRUE' Group by MsgId
```

I think  Msg table has so much data, count() function scan all data in table. It is costly.

I Have some idea for your problem

1-)You can use Nosql db (Mongo,Raven tec.) instead of Msg table . Just write and read Msg data on Nosql db.

2-) Try to add index PopUpStatus on Msg table

3-) You can use summary table for count of Msg table. You can write a job on db this job get Count Msg table  then write the count value different table

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Actually my db is SQL.You want me change to Nosql? your query helped me and i have already index my table.

Comment: No need change mysql . I said you should use both mysql and nosql db. You just use  Nosql  db for your message data instead of mysql . Other data can be store on mysql . This is hybrit solution. If you consider this